# CSS Page Scrolling Right on White Space/Margin and Cross Browser Compatability

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I'm developing http://pizzli.com/darrenwp as a WordPress Theme. For some reason, I cannot get the center container to have equal left and right margins around it and for some reason the page thinks it sees white space and allows me to scroll right. If anyone could provide advice, it would be much appreciated. Also in Internet Explorer the Featured News Area seems to move down and I can't find any reason why.

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: in what resolution you are working? coz putting 1280 everywhere is not good.

Comment: The site is being built from a client mockup that is 1280 by 1800. What would you recommend putting?

Comment: There are so many issue with this particular site Firebugs goes nuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add below css rule to make the content center layout.

1. line 39 style.css

   #nav {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   width: 1260px;}
2. line 33 style.css

   #header {
   background: url("images/warriors.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
   height: 201px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 1280px;
   }
3. line 26 style.css

   #container {
   background: url("images/topbg.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
   height: 1445px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 1112px;
   }

Note: you have to slice you header image according to the width of content, because image have more space in left side of logo.

Use the css `img{border:none;}` to remove blue border from images.

Comment: I just did that and it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: This gonna make sense, but these efforts was not needed if OP had some wrapper kind of thing from starting

Comment: I just reduce the nav width 1280 to 1260px. now try.

Comment: Just sliced down my header image and I still seem to be having issues

Comment: Reduce nav width 1280 to 1260px please. and can you tell my why you are using background image in header instead of using img tag.

Comment: increase height of header so image can be visible properly and remove border:1px solid red; from #header tag. i just put it for testing purpose.

Comment: That fixed that. Should I use the IMG tag instead?

Comment: Yes it is better because it makes sense and good for SEO purpose also. Still you have so many issues in design.

Comment: Can you give me some suggestions on what I should do to clean it up? I would be glad to pay you.

Comment: i need some time to review the whole site and it will take time mean while you can make changes as per your need and if you face problem please comment it. Do you want me to handle you project? i mean designing issues.

Comment: Do you want to talk on Skype or something?

Comment: ablock@pizzli.com. I'm still working on improving my PHP Skills, so if you could look over this site and suggest changes, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: have patients things will be on your side soon

Answer (score 0):

the whitespace should probably occur because of your `display:inline-block` declaration, see [here](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/). Also, when cross-browser compatibility is a must, steer clear of fancy display properties, especially `table` (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp). 
concerning the ie problem, try to wrap your code below the picture into a div and manipulate from there. My guess is that there is some kind of padding issue, or the like.

Comment: I can't seem to find a padding issue. I tried wrapping in a DIV and playing with margins/padding to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is going on with your site but I have some suggestions :

1. your warrior.png is having width of 1280px, and the real logo finishe withing 1098px then why this much of space in that image?
2. there is no wrapper because of this you can not center anything.
3. just after body tag you are making navigation, so how navigation is going to act if there is no parent div? 
   just because of there is no wrapper everything is free and moving here and there.
4. Your footer have no specified width, so this can be a big issue after while.
5. Your header, content and navigation none of them have any relation with each other...

Comment: wrapper around the whole thing,

Comment: Is their a way you can chat with me on this?

Comment: You have low rep so this is not possible to chat over here

Comment: Am I allowed to use Skype or some alternative method?

Comment: MY resolution is 1280 by 1024

Comment: Now there is only one issue remains which is in your image reduce the size and see wonders